# Hosting multiple pages using one HTML file

Tags: html

I want one HTML file with a header that opens another page inside the same page instead of opening it as a new link. I want to host maybe 5 or 6 pages in one file with a div for each. I host with a provider that charges more for more pages, and want to have all pages in one HTML file so I don't have to pay more. The image below shows what I am trying to do:

[image: code]

Comment: Why don't you just do this right and switch providers?  Hosting is dirt cheap.

Comment: i am using free hosting with freenom please help with this if you know anything

Comment: the point is i do not have the money at all to host so thats why im using that service

Comment: Put it on GitHub Pages, or on a free AWS account on S3 for a year.

Comment: i would probably have to pay to get that domain transfered and im a broke person right now lol

Comment: Why would you have to transfer the domain?  (You wouldn't...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with HTML and CSS, with the [`:target` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target).  For example, in HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">C</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section id="a">
  <h1>
    Section A
  </h1>
</section>
<section id="b">
  <h1>
    Section B
  </h1>
</section>
<section id="c">
  <h1>
    Section C
  </h1>
</section>
```

In your CSS:

```
section {
  display: none;
}
section:target {
  display: block;
}
```

You can test it on JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/af180e3j/

Comment: i will test this out and see if it fits my liking then let you know

Comment: ok this is close to what i want, i have a header using a code in css
 #header {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000000;
        }
Then i have buttons i want to put each  of these in

so my question is how would i take it out of list format and put it into a format kinda like this for in the heading  https://imgur.com/a/aAGylQg the list would go into buttons like seen with page 2 button with my old code

Comment: @RichardCooper You just need to link to the correct anchors...  if you can't figure out how to format a link, you should post a different question for that.  Stack Overflow is for clear and specific questions.

Comment: i know how to format likes with a href let me try something to edit this code to work if it doesnt ill let you know

Comment: ok i see what you did the #a #b #c allows it to open the  <section id="letter"> so all i did was this 

<div id="header">
        
        <a href="#a" class="headerbuttons">Home</a>
        <a href="#b" class="headerbuttons">Faucethub</a>
        <a href="#c" class="headerbuttons">Direct</a>
        
    </div>

the class sets it to buttons so it works now thanks